# Testing non-executable library in Netbeans?

Tags: java, testing, netbeans

I am currently working on a Java library - that is, a bunch of classes that are exclusively intended to be used in other projects. Naturally, it has no main() function.

Now, I want to test my progress. And by "test" I don't mean some professional standardized system; I mean I have a very simple function that I want to run to gather information, which will be modified as the project becomes more complete.

I was *hoping* I could drop an executable class into the Test Packages folder, and just click Run. Unfortunately, NetBeans complains that there are no main classes found.

So, how do I test a library project, without adding an executable class to my distributable source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should absolutely look into unit testing frameworks, such as [JUnit](http://junit.org). IDEs typically have support for running tests easily, and [it looks like Netbeans does too](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/junit-intro.html). (I don't use Netbeans myself, but I'd have been shocked if it didn't support JUnit.) It's a *lot* simpler to do this than to have `main` methods everywhere. After all, a `main` method will only test *one* route through your code - with unit tests, you can have *lots* of tests, each testing one small piece of your code.

Even if you don't want to go into unit testing in a fully-fledged way (which I'd strongly urge you to, by the way), unit tests can be a very straightforward way of just running some code and experimenting with it. I sometimes use it when developing against a 3rd party library for the first time - leaving unit tests to show and document my understanding of the library's behaviour. (Obviously the better the library and its documentation, the less need there is for this, but it's still useful...)

Comment: "Simpler" is rather subjective - JUnit creates an entire mess of functions that all fail because I haven't done whatever needs to be done to them, when at the moment I am literally just trying to run: `MyObj test = new MyObj();` and see if it explodes.

Comment: @DigitalMan: JUnit itself doesn't create a mess of functions. You should just be able to create an empty test class and add whatever you need.

Comment: It seems that NetBeans generated the full test suite; further research indicates much greater flexibility than just prodding at every function in a class. I will consider this an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both JUnit and CPPUnit in Netbeans extensively and find that it is fairly easy to get test coverage for libraries with those tools.  IntelliJ IDEA does a decent job with JUnit as well so that is an option if you don't like the Netbeans interface.  The xUnit frameworks have gotten me out of a jam many times since they are very good at isolating errors quickly.  As Jon said they also help to capture the requirements/behavior of your system so that is an added bonus.